# How to dispense thick, intense hot sauce without getting residue on the bottle?

Tags: spicy-hot, kitchen-safety, hot-sauce

I have a bottle of Dave's Insanity Sauce. I enjoy putting it on my food in small quantities and have no trouble handling the heat... in my mouth. The problem is that the outside of the bottle seems to have some capsaicin residue on it. Even when I wash my hands after handling it, I later experience pain if I touch my eyes or my nose or, um, other body parts.

I suspect the problem is that it's a thick, viscous sauce and I'm not able to dispense just a drop or two without getting some on the lip of the bottle (where the threads for the cap are), and from there it seems to spread. Is there a good way to 1) dispense sauces like this cleanly, or 2) make the bottle less hazardous?

Washing the bottle with dish detergent may have helped temporarily, but it would be great to not have to do this every time I use the sauce.

Comment: Just so you aware, speaking as someone who went to college with Dave, that "sauce" is intended as a joke.

Comment: Thanks! I didn't know that. Fortunately I've never claimed to have sophisticated tastes, or good judgement in general, so I feel like I'm free to keep enjoying it.

Comment: Oh, you're not the only one.  I might suggest trying one of Dave's other sauces, though; not only do they have more general flavor, but they would probably eliminate the "16 molecules of sauce got on my hands and I can't touch my eyes" problem.

Comment: @FuzzyChef To be fair, Dave's insanity sauce is 'only' about 50,000 scoville units, whereas something like Magma Hot Sauce is 500,000 scoville units, or even something like 'The Source' which is 7 million. Personally, I just have a jar of capsaicin powder at home that I like to use. :)

Comment: @Onyz : yeah, but it was (one of?) the first commercially packaged hot sauced that included refined capsaicin for heat.  And it was before there was widespread knowledge of "ghost pepper" and other extremely hot varieties in the US.  (I saw an interview with him maybe 20 years ago ... I think it was something like when closing time came around, and there were people who weren't in any hurry to leave, he'd offer people some food (might've been wings), and they could stay if they ate the whole thing.)  So yeah, it was a joke.

Answer (score 1):

Unless you want to go through the faff I do every time I use gravy browning (notorious lid-glue!) - wipe the top of the bottle; rinse the lid under the tap; seal top of bottle with thumb & rinse screw-thread - then why not just thin it down a bit so it's less sticky?

Water or vinegar ought to do it, assuming you at least use boiled water.

Comment: Part of the reason I bought it was so I could experiment with thinning it out, or with making other hot sauces more intense. You're right, it's possible that this will solve the problem.

Comment: Once you've got that sorted your next challenge is to discover why, no matter how much you shake it before or after use, Tabasco always manages to get one teeny solid bit inside the tiny neck that means nothing happens for the first 5 shakes. ;)